# Emscripten without SDL

Tags: c++, opengl-es, webgl, sdl, emscripten

I'm trying to get started with emscripten but I don't seem to be able to find all that much information about it. I have followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Tutorial), and got a simple hello world working. From what I gather the normal `GL` calls automatically get translated into `WebGL`, but what I'm wondering about is how to set up the rendering target, context and all that without `SDL` or `GLUT` or anything along those lines.

Is there a way to use `WebGL` on emscripten without `SDL\GLUT` (including mouse/keyboard input, etc)? Where can I get some more info, examples, etc about emscripten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Cheerp - an alternative to emscripten - [Cheerp](http://www.leaningtech.com/cheerp/) has a working WebGL demo, it also has much more coherent/updated docs/examples

Comment: I'm not a fan of Duetto's proprietary licenses, not to mention that they apparently don't have support for virtual inheritance.

Comment: Duetto is fully FOSS. Duetto headers and libraries are released under the GPL. The compiler itself is released under the LLVM license. At the moment Duetto does not support virtual inheritance, which means that you can't use a virtual base. Virtual calls, even for multiple inheritance are fully supported. Full disclosure, I'm one of Duetto authors and CTO of Leaning Technologies, which is the company behind Duetto. [Edited to add more details to licensing]

Comment: @alexp Thanks for the info, I was misinformed about the license. I'm not entirely sure that I'll be able to make use of it without the virtual base, but I'll surely keep an eye out for it and check it out as soon as that's available. Cheers.

Comment: "I suggest you use duetto" is worth looking at if you don't want to port existing code. Emscritpen and Duetto have TOTTALY distinct objectives. There is no "better" or "worse". If you want full C++ compliance (except for some minor details like unaligned memory, etc., where you need to take special care) then you NEED emscripten. If you want to write a new browser project, but want to use a decent programming language like C++11, then Duetto might well be worth a shot (I never tried it myself since I stopped at its feature list, not C++ standard compliant => not working for me)

Comment: Probably important clarification: Duetto (now Cheerp) includes dual-licensed components. If you want to use the Cheerp libraries in a non-GPL project, you have to pay for the privilege: http://www.leaningtech.com/cheerp/buy/

Comment: Cheerp lacks of many gl instructions and does not fit for any project, unfortunately. It's mainly targeted for math functions and DOM manipulation.